# Hadoop serialization - How to read User object from java.io.DataInput

Tags: java, serialization, hadoop, mapreduce, java-io

I need to create a generic parser to find the min/max/SD of all integer parameters using MapReduce program. For example, I get files with different number of integer parameters say one file with 30 param and other with 40, but with first 2 generic param ID & EventTime.
When I tried to create generic parser I used a class **GenericParser** with

```
long eventTime;
MinMaxTuple[] params;
```

In Mapper class I used GenericParser as Value. But Serialization fails since I cast the default DataInput as ObjectInput and DataOutput as ObjectOutput so as to read and write as Object.

```
@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException 
  ObjectOutput objOut = (ObjectOutput) out;

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException 
  ObjectInput objIn = (ObjectInput) in;
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer$BlockingBuffer cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectOutput
        at com.csc.test.vehicle.parsers.GenericParser.write(GenericParser.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableSerializer.serialize(WritableSerialization.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableSerializer.serialize(WritableSerialization.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1074)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:591)
```

How can I override the serialization process to overcome this problem of using `ObjectInput` and `ObjectOutput` instead on default `DataInput` and `DataOutput`? Or, is there an alternate solution? Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Why u want your own serialization? Since hadoop writes/reads object using their own serialization mechanism. Also MinMaxTuple, is it Writable?

Comment: We would be able to Serialize primitive data types. But in this case, I need to serialize `GenericParser` which internally has UserObject (MinMaxTuple). The `readFields()` and `write()` allow `DataInput` and `DataOutput` as parameters using which UserObject are not allowed to serialize.

Comment: could u implement Writable interface in MinMaxTuple , if sso hadoop itself manage it.